# Rails 3 association eager load vs opposite association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations, eager-loading

I have associated models like this:

```
class Batch
  has_many :logs

class Log
  belongs_to :batch
```

I'm using includes to load batches with logs:

```
b = Batch.includes(:logs)
```

Which runs 2 selects as expected (batches and logs).

Then I do

```
b.first.logs.first.batch
```

and this triggers another select on batches, even when they were actually loaded already.
I figured to "fix" it by doing includes(:logs => :batch) but I'm still thinking that something is wrong here because the same batches are loaded twice. What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this with the :inverse_of setting, which lets ActiveRecord know that the two associations are the inverse of each other.

```
class Batch
  has_many :logs, :inverse_of => :batch
end

class Log
  belongs_to :batch, :inverse_of => :logs
end
```

Comment: Thx, never noticed this before!